# how to rewrite a c expression to involve pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently completing some homework where we read an input, and load the input into a string, and stop reading when certain conditions are not met.

I've now been prompted to re-write my line 5 to involve pointer arithmetic, without square bracket notation.

```
int readLine(char*s, int MAX){
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i<MAX){
    s[i++] = c;
  }
  s[i]= '\0';
  return i;
}
```

would it be *s = i;?

Comment: If s is the address of the first element in the string, i.e. s = &s[0], and each character occupies a single byte, where might the fifth element of the string be located?  Remember that arrays start at zero.  You should be able to come up with an expression like s[i] = *(s + ....)

Comment: the square notation is a quick/simpler way of addressing the value in a pointer. var[x] equals *(var+x)

Comment: `char c; c = getchar()` is wrong.  `getchar` returns an int, and if you want to reliably check for EOF, you must use an integer type.  eg `int c; while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX )...`. (Note that this implies that failing to check for EOF is wrong, which is also true.)

Answer (score 1):

You *are* using pointer arithmetic. `x[ y ]` performs pointer arithmetic.

But you also said you want to avoid the square bracket syntax. Since [`x[ y ]` is 100% equivalent to `*( x + y )`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/589924), that's easy.

Finally, the grader is possibly expecting you to go further and avoid adding `i` to `s` repeatedly. This can be done by modifying `s` itself.

Comment: so i could rewrite line 5 to be s=*(s+i); ? or would i use *(c+i)

Comment: wait i think i got it. s[i++] = c; is equivalent to c = *(s+i);

Comment: `=` is not commutative.

Comment: you also still need the `++`.  So the equivalent is `*(s + i++) = c;`